# Search for particular string and print between particular strings -- Linux Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell

This is my file.

```
'#### 
OutOfmemory is the error which has occured
Log Error
Sample
'####
Incident Dump Executor 
Test
Notinhg
'####
Sample
test
'####
OutOfmemory Sample
This is what i want
'####
```

From this file, i want to find OutOfmemory and once it found i need to print the lines beween ####

`OutOfmemory`  occurs two times, so I want output like this:

```
'#### 
OutOfmemory is the error which has occured
Log Error
Sample
'####

'####
OutOfmemory Sample
This is what i want
'####
```

I don't want remaining lines in my output.

Comment: This question is illegible. If you want people to help you, please use code formatting for code. Also, I don't see you ask a question. StackOverflow is for precise questions, so you must not only state your problem, but also show what your approach is so far, and where exactly you're encountering problems.

Comment: sorry i changed now

Comment: As far as the algorithm goes, it should be enough to keep a running buffer and an "OutOfMemory" flag. Read lines one by one, adding them to the buffer. If they include "OutOfMemory", set the flag to true. If they match "###", print the entire buffer if the flag is true, then set the flag to false, clear the buffer and continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using gnu-awk you can do this:

```
awk -v RS="'####" 'BEGIN{ORS=RS "\n\n"} /OutOfmemory/{print RT $0}' file

'####
OutOfmemory is the error which has occured
Log Error
Sample
'####

'####
OutOfmemory Sample
This is what i want
'####
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` with the `-A` (after) and the `-B` (before) options, you can specify how many lines to show after/before the match is found.
Suppose your file is named `foo`, you can do like this:

```
cat foo | grep -i -B 1 -A 2 "OutOfmemory"
```